# How do I make the "position:" in my code more precise?

Tags: c++, linux

I finally finished this code but there is one problem: for the output "Positions:" I want it to output every position where the minimum occurs. However, my code only outputs the last position of the minimum in each randomly generated array (size 20). Please direct me into how I can make this program less redundant while outputting the multiple positions where the minimum occurs. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double random(unsigned int &seed);
unsigned int seed = (unsigned int)time(0);
const int SIZE = 20;

void print_array (int a[]);
void fill_array (int a []);
int find_min (int [], int);

int main ()
{
  int arr[SIZE];
  cout << "Arrays: \n";
  fill_array(arr);
  print_array(arr);

  int pos = find_min(arr, SIZE); 
  int minimum = arr[pos];

  cout << "Min is: " << minimum << endl;
  cout << "At position: " << pos +1 << endl; 

  return 0;
  }

double random(unsigned int &seed)
{
   const int MODULUS = 15749;
   const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
   const int INCREMENT = 1;
   seed = ((MULTIPLIER*seed)+INCREMENT)%MODULUS;
   return double(seed)/MODULUS;
   }

void fill_array (int a [])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
      a[i] = 0 + (10 * (random(seed)));
}

int find_min (int arr[], int n)
{
   int min = arr[0]; 
   int index = 0;

   for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
     if (arr[i] < min) 
     {
        index = i;
        min = arr[i];
     }
   return index;
 }

 void print_array (int a[])
 {
    for (int i = 0; i <SIZE; ++i)
      cout << setw(3) << a[i];
 cout << endl;
 }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for. Please read [ask] questions

Comment: The OP wants to look again in the array to find the min value and output every index containing that value.

Comment: Hello, my question is: where in this program can I edit my find_min function to output the positions (instead of just one position (the last position) of where the minimum occurs). Here is a sample output:                         Arrays:  0  1  8  0  8  8  2  1  1  9  4  1  4  1  9  8  5  4  2  3
Minimum is: 0
Positions: 1 ----- this is where I want the position output to be: 1, 4

Comment: Search from pos+1 to n-1 for every occurrence of min. While you are searching if min is found print it and pos.

Comment: I would not edit find_min.

Comment: thank you, also would that require a loop in the int main() ?

Comment: You can do that or make a new function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by changing your `main`. Please see the below code

```
int main ()
{
  int arr[SIZE];
  cout << "Arrays: \n";
  fill_array(arr);
  print_array(arr);

  int pos = find_min(arr, SIZE); 
  int minimum = arr[pos];

  //The following loop traverses through the array and prints the position when array element is equals to minimum
  for (int i = pos; i < SIZE; i++) {
     if (arr[i] == minimum)
       cout << "Min is at: " << i+1 << endl;    
  }

  cout << "Min is: " << minimum << endl;
  cout << "At position: " << pos +1 << endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

**EDITED:** For printing in one line you can do something like the following code -

```
cout << "Min is at: "
for (int i = pos; i < SIZE; i++) {
         if (arr[i] == minimum) {

             if (i != pos) cout << ", ";

             cout << i+1 << endl;


         }

 }
```

However, there are many formatting options. You can use any of them.

Comment: thank you so much! Although I was about to try a for loop, I was hesitating on using the condition if (arr[i] == minimum). Thank you once again! Not a major problem, but I was wondering, how may I output the "Min is at: " as a list on one line? Such as: "Min is at: 2, 6, 9" instead of

Comment: Right. I missed that. Thanks for figuring out. Edited.

Comment: yes, I want the output on one line but still haven't figure out how to

Comment: @peso Please see my Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate everyone's help! After reading the chapter on loops (Deitel's C++) I also found this method to enable the positions to be on one line:                                                                        
    cout << "Positions: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (arr[i] == minimum)
            cout << i+1 << " ";
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}                                                                      which is quite similar to the edit you made, just a different formatting approach. Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @peso is your issue fixed?

Comment: thank you, I'm new to this site and just realized that I hadn't accepted the answer yet. I did so right now and once again, thank you so much!